# Error with hist function (need finite 'ylim' values) (breaks related)

Tags: r, statistics, histogram, distribution

Could anyone tell why running `hist` on matrix CHh gives error "Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", ...) : need finite 'ylim' values"? If I eliminate the min function the error disappears. Yet I don't understand why that represents a problem. Thank you.

```
CFh <-structure(c(-0.64, 0.34, 0.65, 0.26, -0.64, 0.92, -0.64, -0.1, -0.41, -0.36, 0.16, 0.92, 1.43, -0.41, 0.65, 0.28, 0.47, 0.35, -0.54, 0.65, 0.28, -0.1, 0.92, -0.36, 0.25, 0.34, -0.34, 0.07, 0.65, 0, -0.04, 0.47, 0.78, 0.47, 1.43, -0.23, -0.41, 0.28, 0.62, 0.35, -0.34, -0.23, -0.36, 0.28, 0.26, 0.03, 0.28, 0.07, 0.47, 0.63, 0.35, 0.47, 0, -0.28, 0.34, 0.16, 0.62, -0.04, 0.03, -0.41, -0.34, -0.64, -0.32, -0.28, -0.04, -0.36, 0.34, 0.47, 0.63, 0.62, 0, -0.04, -0.23, 0.65, -0.04, 0.47, -0.64, 0, -0.34, 0.28, -0.1, -0.28, 0.35, -0.34, -0.04, 0.63, 0.92, 0.35, 0.25, 0.34, 0.25, 0.34, 0.16, -0.36, 0, 0.28, 0.28, -0.28, -0.34, -0.23, 0.78, -0.41, 0.65, -0.32, -0.54, -0.36, 0.92, 0.25, 0.47, -0.1, 0.78, -0.54, 0.63, 0.65, -0.28, 0.25, 0.07, 0.35, 0.62, -0.28, -0.36, -0.54, 0.47, 0.47, 1.43, 0.63, -0.28, 0.03, 0.92, 0.92), .Dim = c(26L, 5L))
Breaks <- c(max(CFh,1.0), 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0,
            -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4, -0.5, -0.6, -0.7, -0.8, -0.9, -1.0, min(CFh,-1.0))
h <- hist(CFh, plot=TRUE, breaks=Breaks)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have repeated values in your `Breaks` vector. This causes a problem with binning. Make sure the values are unique

```
  h <- hist(CFh, plot=TRUE, breaks=unique(Breaks))
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on from the above solution,
using unique breaks,
you could also consider a simpler way to create breaks as a sequence

```
Breaks <- unique(c(max(CFh,1.0), seq(1, -1, by=-0.1), min(CFh,-1.0)))
h <- hist(CFh, plot=TRUE, breaks=Breaks)
```